# Suggestions for OSB coating

Tags: finishing, staining

I am making shelves from OSB. I have find in Internet that it is possible to apply some coating so that OSB will be shining and smooth.

Can you please suggest some type of coating/stain/finish (can't really understand difference between them) that will fill rough surface of OSB?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCPlL9UQGT4 be ready to collect your books from the floor if you put heavy books on the shelf...

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could coat it in a "bar top epoxy", which is an epoxy resin that flows out to a nice degree of flatness. That's a pricey option.

But the better question is, why would you save a couple of bucks on osb (which is typically not thick enough to be good shelf material... *I'll correct my answer if you tell me that you're using 1" or thicker stock, or that you've designed wooden stiffeners into the shelf, or that your shelves have a really short span*) when you could buy some decent plywood and have fewer issues from the outset?

If you're stuck on osb and don't want to splash out for the epoxy, a few coats of varnish would at least keep the wood fibers down. It still wouldn't "fill the rough surface" as your question requested.

Comment: +1 on the poured epoxy finish, that's the only thing to use here. But about OSB, in my experience OSB is quite stiff even at 1/2" (12mm here), and 18mm stuff is even stronger of course. Regardless of any material's outright strength/stiffness though the span of the shelf is everything. Even thin pine is fine for a shelf that's only got a 14" span and will only ever support a few nick nacks.